# FC multipath says "device busy " when connecting again. SLES 11 - netapp - emulex

Tags: mount, automount, multipath

I have a weird issue.

sles 11
emulex FC
netapp fas 2xxx

100G LUN is ok.
Multipath enabled, multipathd and device-mapper seem to work properly.

multipath -t shows this output of the config => http://pastebin.com/bmEBhdeX

When both FC are connected I get this output from multipath -ll

360a98000572d5073538f68484c4c512f dm-0 NETAPP,LUN
[size=200G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
_ round-robin 0 [prio=8][active]
_ 1:0:0:70 sdc 8:32 [active][ready]
_ 2:0:0:70 sde 8:64 [active][ready]
_ round-robin 0 [prio=2][enabled]
_ 1:0:1:70 sdb 8:16 [active][ready]
_ 2:0:1:70 sdd 8:48 [active][ready]

When I unplug one FC everything goes fine.

The issue appears when connecting again, on the desktop a sdb or sdc "device is busy" . And then it does not appear on multipath -ll.

I though it could be that automount or similar tries to mount the sdb or sdc device, put they are not in the fstab and automount is not running.

Any suggestions?

thanks.

PD: Just in case you are curious the messages file => http://pastebin.com/2PfxSDKE (look arround 13pm and 15pm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the crucial point where things break is:

```
15:36:09 aoldbsuse hald: mounted /dev/sdc1
...
15:36:09 aoldbsuse multipathd: 360a98000572d5073536f68484c4c512f: failed in domap for addition of new path sdc
```

It seems you do have hald-based automatic mounting in place, so you need to turn it off (no idea how, besides disabling entire hald). Chances are [this link](http://forums.novell.com/suse/suse-product-discussion-forums/suse-linux-enterprise/suse-linux-enterprise-server-sles/sles-configure-administer/print-407722-how-disable-sles11-automount-san-non-fstab-disks.html) will be helpful, or the support note mentioned there.

Comment: if link not working --> http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/469376-if-i-disable-hald-addon-will-plug-play-still-work.html